# Issue with @media query in CSS with responsive design

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

In my below, I am adding two `divs` inside a main div called `block` and arranging one in left and another in right.I am putting a border for the main div `block`

But the problem I am facing here is, when the screen size is below 300px, the two child div will arrange one by one, but the border not aligning properly. Border not covering two child `divs` entirely. How to resolve this border issue.

Another issue is, this code not working in IE (checking with IE11). what parameter I have to add \ modify to work this with IE

**[Fiddle Setup](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/8h28n/1/)**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Your devices are sequential ?</div>
        <div class="input-resp">
            <input type="radio" name="button" value="Yes" /><label>Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="button" value="No"  /><label>No</label>
        </div>
    </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
width: inherit;
width: 96%; 
max-width: 700px;
margin: auto;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#ddd;
height:20%;
padding:1%;

}
.input-quest {
width: 60%;
float:left;
}
.input-resp {
width: 40%;
text-align: center;
float:right;
}

@media (max-width:300px) {

.input-resp {
background-color:red;
width: 100%;
float:left;
text-align:left;
}

.input-quest {
background-color:green;
width: 100%;
float:left;
text-align:left;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `height` set to `20px` on your `.block` div. So you would either need to remove that in the `@media` call or set a new `height`. You also should clear some of your `floats` in your main CSS and remove them in your `@media` query.

See your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XYMtx/1/